# Is there a way to select and edit the next occurrence in a case independent (yet, respective) fashion?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor, text-manipulation

Example, let's say you have the text:

foo Foo

foo

You select the first 'foo' and perform the keyboard shortcut for 'next occurrence', ideally highlighting 'Foo' (not the second 'foo'). You then proceed to type

bar

on your keyboard.

The text changes to:

bar Bar

foo

Does **anyone** have any clue how to do this?

Sorry if the wording is, well, wordy, I didn't know how else to say it.

Here's a gif that explains the behavior I'm looking for:

In the gif, I would like to select object and Object, type error, and have the result by error and setError.

[image: select and respect next camelhumps and change]

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do it with the case respective way.

Comment: There HAS to be a way. I've got my mind in React Hook land right now and can't really pry it away, otherwise I'd try and think about how to do it. Could you give an upvote so maybe we can one day learn?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can just use `Edit | Find | Replace...`:

1. first select 'foo'
2. invoke Replace (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on the Mac)
3. click the Preserve Case check box
4. type 'bar' in the replacement text field
5. click Replace (or Replace All if you're feeling  )

Comment: Oh my god this works. Okay, now we have to figure how to turn this into a keyboard shortcut in IntelliJ. Can you help me out with that? I'll try on my own as well. Upvoting and will accept once we get that working.

Comment: So if I map replace to <keybinding>, I can highlight and replace the words (with your tip about Preserve Case). Is there a way to make this work more succinctly?